# How to call data from parse in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to retrieve data from parse but I keep getting a not found on object of type PFObject for startingBalance.

Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.startingBalance);
    }


}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PFObject is effectively an NSDictionary - at least when it comes to accessing the attributes - so you can access an attribute via `objectForKey` or the shorthand `[]` syntax -

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object[@"startingBalance"]);
    }


}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the object a subclass of your given object type. So in this case, instead of getting an array of generic PFObject you get an array of Account objects.

Comment: This won't work because `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` will return `PFObject`s not your sub-class